# How to do a "time-slice" in packets in a network dump with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from scapy.all import *

pkts = rdpcap("/home/anadikrsna/Desktop/lalalao2.pcap")

somaMin = pkts[0].time + 600


valores=[]
for p in pkts:

    if p<=somaMin:
        #armazenando os valores que estiverem dentro do intervalo de tempo
        valores.append(p)

    else:


        print "os valores",valores

        valores=[]
        valores.append(p)
        somaMin=p.time+ 600
```

#

I'm trying to "catch" source IPs and destination IPs inside a network dump (PCAP) file. The idea is to save all source IPs and all destination IPs by slicing the file by 10 minutes ("time-slice").

How to "split" the packets every 10 min and then save source IP and destination IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 minutes is 600 seconds.

You can just subtract the current packet time from the first one and see if 10 minutes passed (because timestamps are in seconds).

Do this for every 10 minutes of packets in your pcap.

The following code will make you a list of lists - every sublist represents 10 minutes of packets.

```
packets = []
temp = []
t1 = pkts[0].time
t2 = 0
for p in pkts:
    t2 = p.time
    if (t2 - t1) > 600:
        t1 = p.time
        packets.append(temp)
        temp = []
        temp.append(p)
    else:
        temp.append(p)
```

Then, to address each of the sublists:

```
for pkt_list in packets:
    print pkt_list # OR do other stuff with it. Each pkt_list is 10 minutes of packets
```

If you want to get each packet's src and dest ip, I suggest you do it in the first loop that runs on all packets. Use this to address the IP addresses inside the first loop(`for p in pkts`) and do whatever you want with it:

```
if IP in p: #if packet has IP layer
    src_ip = p[IP].src
    dest_ip = p[IP].dst
```

**EDIT -** the above code runs in every loop of the for loop. If you want to print all src_ip you found, first init a list - `src_ip_addresses = []`, in the beginning of your code. Then, each time you find `IP` layer in the packet, do:

```
src_ip_addresses.append(src_ip)
```

And in the end of your code, print each element in that list.

Comment: But 1488498263.14 is not timestamp? I dont understand!

Comment: @AnadiKrsnadas it is! all are timestamps. You can suctract them (as the code shows) to get the time difference in seconds between them.

Comment: Thanks! I am newbie in programming.

Comment: @AnadiKrsnadas no worries. try to understand the code and then run it. If it helped you, upvote and/or approve the answer.

Comment: How can I print a sublist with all packets inside?

Comment: Sorry for my dumb question. I am try to understand the code! I need to access each list to do some calculation!

Comment: I tried to run the code including the "for pkt_list in packets:
    print pkt_list" but there is no print and I got no error!

Comment: Could you, please, help me?

Comment: packets[counter] = temp
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @AnadiKrsnadas to solve the indexError, look at the change I did in the code. Debug your code - print the packets in the loop and see the value during the run. Try to understand where it gets lost.

Comment: How can I save each src_ip on different line? The code above made a mess in the file!

Comment: @AnadiKrsnadas Your image code is indented very badly. The writing-to-file code should only be done after you have collected all ip_src addresses. Look at the change I made in the code up^.